# Getting Warning as NoSuchAlgorithmException in vert.x

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, vert.x

I have implemented a backend call protected via bearer authentication to the Keycloak's userinfo endpoint using access token in vert.x framework. I am able to run this code without any errors.
But I am getting this warning:

```
> May 16, 2022 10:33:04 AM
io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2AuthProviderImpl WARNING: Skipped
> unsupported JWK: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA-OAEP
```

Below is the code:

```
> OAuth2ClientOptions clientOptions = new OAuth2ClientOptions()
>                 .setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE)
>                 .setSite(System.getProperty("oauth2.issuer", "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm"))
>                 .setClientID(System.getProperty("oauth2.client_id", "myclientid"))
>                 .setClientSecret(System.getProperty("oauth2.client_secret",
> "myclientscret"));
> 
> private Handler<RoutingContext> UserInfo(WebClient webClient, String
> userInfoUrl) {
> 
>         return (RoutingContext ctx) -> {
> 
>             OAuth2TokenImpl user = (OAuth2TokenImpl) ctx.user();
> 
>             URI userInfoEndpointUri = URI.create(userInfoUrl);
>             webClient
>                     .get(userInfoEndpointUri.getPort(), userInfoEndpointUri.getHost(), userInfoEndpointUri.getPath())
>                     .bearerTokenAuthentication(user.opaqueAccessToken())
>                     .as(BodyCodec.jsonObject())
>                     .send(ar -> {
>                         JsonObject body = ar.result().body();
>                         respondWithOk(ctx, "application/json", body.encodePrettily());
>                     });
>         };
>     }
```

Dependencies are as follows:

```
> <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>vertx-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
>             <version>3.9.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
>             <version>3.9.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
>             <version>3.9.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
>             <version>3.9.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
>             <artifactId>vertx-auth-jwt</artifactId>
>             <version>3.9.1</version>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
```

How to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore this warning, it is [just a warning on purpose](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/issues/279).

Comment: I'm using JWTAuth in my application and would need to support RSA-OAEP alg. Is it possible to extend the support by providing custom implementation for this? I couldn't find any vert.x documentation mentioning this.

Comment: @Hegdekar you can always contribute support for this. The source you should start looking is: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-common/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/impl/jose/JWK.java#L409 First you need to add the algorithm you need, and then ensure that the https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/d71b5ff1cdfd3c5e4fd04fd468fade2a7e452bdd/vertx-auth-common/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/impl/jose/JWK.java#L468-L504 method can create a new key

Comment: Well. It seems to not be a warning any longer. It is a `RuntimeException` now. -.-

Answer (score 1):

As this now throws a `RuntimeException` you might want to disable the key provider:

- open Keycloak Admin, select the Realm used
- go to `Realm settings > Keys > Providers`
- click on `rsa-enc-generated`: switch `enabled` and `active` to off

*In one instance, `rsa-enc-generated` was already set to disabled/deactivated. When I set it on and off again and hit the save button, the provider is actually disabled and the error disappears. But in a later instance it was correctly shown as enabled/active and I had to disable it to fix the error.*