# Vert.x and Keycloak 19.0.1

Tags: java, keycloak, vert.x

I am trying to use keycloak for my SSO in vert.x. The keycloak version is 19.0.1 and vert.x version is 4.3.3. I am getting the following error and I am stuck at it for a while. Please could some one help me in this?

Sep 09, 2022 11:52:03 AM io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2AuthProviderImpl
WARNING: Unsupported JWK
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA-OAEP
at io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.jose.JWK.(JWK.java:464)
at io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.impl.OAuth2AuthProviderImpl.lambda$jWKSet$2(OAuth2AuthProviderImpl.java:129)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition.onSuccess(Composition.java:38)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition$1.onSuccess(Composition.java:62)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.SucceededFuture.addListener(SucceededFuture.java:88)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition.onSuccess(Composition.java:43)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition$1.onSuccess(Composition.java:62)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition$1.onSuccess(Composition.java:62)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition$1.onSuccess(Composition.java:62)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.SucceededFuture.addListener(SucceededFuture.java:88)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition.onSuccess(Composition.java:43)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:86)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.execute(ContextBase.java:225)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:51)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpEventHandler.handleEnd(HttpEventHandler.java:79)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientResponseImpl.handleEnd(HttpClientResponseImpl.java:250)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection$StreamImpl.lambda$new$0(Http1xClientConnection.java:397)
at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.handleEvent(InboundBuffer.java:239)
at io.vertx.core.streams.impl.InboundBuffer.write(InboundBuffer.java:129)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection$StreamImpl.handleEnd(Http1xClientConnection.java:624)
at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:76)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.execute(ContextBase.java:232)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection.handleResponseEnd(Http1xClientConnection.java:858)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection.handleHttpMessage(Http1xClientConnection.java:730)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xClientConnection.handleMessage(Http1xClientConnection.java:694)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:157)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA-OAEP
at io.vertx.ext.auth.impl.jose.JWK.(JWK.java:412)
... 62 more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Warning as NoSuchAlgorithmException in vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254461/getting-warning-as-nosuchalgorithmexception-in-vert-x)

Comment: Unfortunately the linked thread provides no helpful information. @vasu-sethia did you find a solution for your problem?